# Adding TLS to docker nginx container, how is a nginx-proxy container supposed to bind to the same port?

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, containers

I'm in a unique situation where I am trying to write a docker-compose file for configured containers that are already running, which I believe I got down. Now I am trying to add TLS security to it.

I came across [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), which looks like a great solution as I believe I would run a proxy container. But how do I bind to the same port that the nginx container is running on?

My nginx is on port `80`, exposed `80`. The proxy is on `80`. I tried `docker-compose up` with removing the port from nginx also, to no avail.

TLS always seems to be a pain to setup, but I keep trying to dive into the problem without fear, and maybe it is just a misunderstanding of major networking concepts that are holding me back.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=long-qualified-subdomain.domain.com
    volumes:
      - /opt/var/www/site:/var/www/site:rw
      - /opt/etc/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
    links:
        - php-fpm
  php-fpm:
    image: php-fpm:pdo_mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /opt/var/www/site:/var/www/site:rw
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to have ports exposed. Containers can talk to each other even if ports are not exposed. Only have the `80` port exposed of the `nginx-proxy` container so you can access it using the browser (expose the `443` port as well). Tl;dr drop the `expose` of the `nginx` container.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `- "80:80"` in one of the containers to something like `- "8080:80"` (or some other open port on your host than `8080`.

That'll expose that container to a different port than `80` on the host machine, while still keeping it as port `80` within the container. Usually a reverse proxy will only need to point to the internal port of the container, rather than it's exposed port (assuming you have the containers within the same Docker network).

You may also be interested in another popular Nginx container that also handles certs automatically, and includes a ton of pre-configured reverse proxies for a lot of the more popular containers: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt

That's the one I've been using for about a year and a half and it makes it all a piece of cake.